# How to fail an AWS ECS task when a non essential container fails to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS task that consists of three containers:

1. S3-pull. This container pulls data from S3
2. Computation. This container performs a computation on data pulled by S3-pull. Depends on S3-pull success, i.e. completing with exit code 0.
3. S3-push. This container copies result of the Computation container to another S3 bucket. Depends on Computation success and is marked as essential.

The problem is that if either S3-pull or Computation container fails to start, for example because of misconfiguration like pointing to a wrong log group, then the ECS task does not fail but is stuck in limbo until it hits the time out. At the same time I can not mark S3-pull and Computation containers as essential because an essential container can not have other containers depending on it. So is there a way to fail the whole task once one of its non essential containers has failed to start and not wait until time out?

Comment: did you consider splitting them into three different tasks?

Comment: @Ali yes, I did. That is undesirable because in that case I need to provide a shared drive for these three tasks and manage it myself, since they can end up on different machines in the cluster. By having three containers in the same task that is managed by ECS.

Comment: In that case, you can consider tweaking the startTimeout and decrease it to a value that is ideal i.e. as small as possible but large enough to guarantee that your container will start. The default is three minutes which might be a little too high in your case.